# Using Oozie workflow and coordinator - E0302: Invalid parameter error

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I'm trying to run a workflow using a coordinator, but when i try to set the workflow and coordinator XML file paths together, i get an error.
This is how my jobs.properties file looks like:

```
nameNode=hdfs://10.74.6.155:9000
jobTracker=10.74.6.155:9010
queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/examples/apps/test/
oozie.coord.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/examples/apps/test/
```

when i run my workflow with the command line:

```
bin\oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config examples\apps\test\job.properties -run
```

i get the following error:

```
Error: E0302 : E0302: Invalid parameter [{0}]
```

what am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both workflow and coordination paths cannot exist in job.properties at the same time. You can either run a job as a workflow or as a coordination.

Answer (score 2):

Use only your Coordinator path in your properties file and use your workflow path in the Coordinator.xml file.

`**oozie.use.system.libpath=true
workflowpath=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/examples/apps/test/
oozie.coord.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/examples/apps/test/**`

In your coordinator.xml file add this line

'`<app-path>${workflowpath}</app-path>`'